# How to access property defined in code-behind from markup in Web Forms User Control

Tags: asp.net

I have a User control (PlacementUI.ascx) that has a property defined in its code-behind.

```
//PlacementUI.ascx.cs
public partial class PlacementUI : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   public PlacementDTO DataItem { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access that property in the markup ?
tried this but it says DataItem does not exist in the current context

```
<div class= '<%# DataItem.CssClass %>'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ugly inline approach:

```
<div class= '<%# ((PlacementDTO)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem")).CssClass%>'>
```

other approach, you need to make the div `runat=server` and give it an `ID`:

```
<div runat="server" id="MyDivId">
```

in codebehind (it is a `HtmlGenericControl`):

```
MyDivId.Attributes["class"] = DataItem.CssClass;
```

You could also use a [`Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel(v=vs.90).aspx) which is rendered as `div`.

```
<asp:Panel id="MyPanel" runat="server" />
```

codebehind:

```
MyPanel.CssClass = DataItem.CssClass;
```

Comment: Weird how it's so much easier to do in a page than in a user control.